# No module found named toplevelfolder when importing github Scrapy project into Scrapinghub

Tags: scrapy, scrapinghub

When I am trying to import my Scrapy project onto Scrapinghub using the website through GitHub I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sfb'
```

Here is my project structure:

```
requirements.txt
scrapy.cfg
sfb---
-------items.py
-------middlewares.py
-------pipelines.py
-------settings.py
-------spiders---
-----------------_init_.py
-----------------spider1.py
-----------------spider2.py
-----------------spider3.py
-----------------spider4.py
-----------------spider5.py
-----------------spider6.py
-----------------spider7.py
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'sfb'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['sfb.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'sfb.spiders'
```

My `_init_.py` is empty.

Comment: needs `_init_.py` file in sfb folder

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out missing `_init_.py` in sfb folder.